# C++ Compiler Error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I am having an issue when trying to populate a 2D array full of objects of a class I have created. The error is:

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Cell *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

The code that generates the error is as follows:

Excerpt from main.cpp

```
Cell cells[80][72];

for(int x = 0; x < 80; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < 72; y++){
        cells[x][y] = new Cell();
    }
}
```

Excerpt from cell.hpp

```
class Cell
{
public:
    Cell();
    int live;
    int neighbours;
};
```

Excerpt from cell.cpp

```
Cell::Cell()
{
    srand(time(0));
    this->live = rand() % 2;
    this->neighbours = 0;
}
```

I suspect that I need an overload of some kind on the constructor of the Cell class but I have no idea how to implement one for this case.

Comment: Do you need an array of `Cell` __pointers__ or an array of `Cell` __objects__? I assume you don't actually want to use `new` in this case. You also don't want to call `srand()` in the `Cell` constructor. Just call `srand()` once in your `main()`.

Comment: Don't use `new` anyway. Use something that manages dynamic memory for you if you actually need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Cell` has a parameterless constructor the statement

```
Cell cells[80][72];
```

defines an 80x72 array of `Cell` objects. The objects are already constructed for you so the nested `for` loops are unnecessary.

On the other hand if you declare `Cell` as a 80x72 array of pointers to `Cell`, i.e.

```
Cell* cells[80][72];
```

Then you have to go allocate each one like you're trying to do.
If you don't actually need to use pointers, then don't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Cell *cells[80][72] = {}
```

You can use **new** only for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing new Cell you create a Cell *.
By the way when you write cell[X][Y] there is nothing else to allocate.

You would do a new if you had :

```
cell ** matrix = new cell[X];
for(int i=0;i<X;i++){
    matrix[i]=new cell[Y];
}
```

But here, in the code you send, it is useless to do the "populate", the cells are already there and allocated